Slanted div at one side
i am looking for the good solution on how to create a slanted div shape at one side like that one on attached screen shot, the shape should be automatically adjust its size to properly handle all contents inside it  when resizing the screen into different sizes...
assume i have something like this
                  ``<div class="container">
               <!---insert the shape here--->
               <div class="row">
                <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum ...</p>
             </div>
           </div>`

`
find the attached screen shot here

https://css-shape.com/slanted-edge/
